# Django date filter: how come the format used is different from the one in datetime library?

Tags: python, django, datetime, date, format

For formatting a date using *date* filter you must use the following format :

```
{{ my_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}
```

If you use *strftime* from the standard *datetime*, you have to use the following :

```
my_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

So my question is ... isn't it ugly (I guess it is because of the `%` that is used also for tags, and therefore is escaped or something) ?

But that's not the main question ... I would like to use the same `DATE_FORMAT` parametrized in `settings.py` all over the project, but it therefore seems that I cannot ! Is there a work around (for example a filter that removes the `%` after the date has been formatted like `{{ my_date|date|dream_filter }}`, because if I just use `DATE_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d"` I got something like `%2001-%6-%12`)?

Comment: Why can't you use [localization](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/localization/#id3)?

Comment: This is not the problem... The problem is that I would like to use the setting's date format for both templates and in my code, but as filter 'date' and library datetime use different FORMATTING SYNTAXES, it seems not to be possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this may not be the "right" answer, I got around this by adding another variable to settings and using it all over the place.  I have dates formatted in JavaScript, `datetime`, and Django templates, so I added all three.

```
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Phoenix'  
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'm-d-Y H:m:s T'
DATE_FORMAT = _('m-d-Y')       
JS_DATE_FORMAT = _('mm-dd-yy')
PERC_DATE_FORMAT = _('%m-%d-%Y')
```

I also run them through localization for our customers in Mexico who prefer a different format.

Comment: Thanks ! I did this to ... But I hoped there would be "THE right solution" :)

Answer (score 3):

use DATE_INPUT_FORMATS.

```
from django.conf import settings
py_format = settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not part of your main question but could be handy anyway. I found it mentioned in the docs that the date filter format is based on php's [date format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing a custom filter:

```
#app/templatetags/python_date.py
from datetime import date, datetime

from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='pythondate')
def python_date_filter(value, arg):
    if not type(value) == date and not type(value) == datetime:
        raise Exception('Value passed in to the filter must be a date or a datetime.')

    return value.strftime(str(arg))
```

usage in templates:

```
{% load python_date %}

{{ some_date|pythondate:'%Y-%m-%d' }}
```